# Import Spring @Configuration for specific profile(s)

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have `@Configuration` class in a shared library with multiple `@Bean` definitions.

I suppose to import this configuration using `@Import` annotation above my main configuration class. The extra thing I'd like to configure is to enable this configuration import only for specific profiles (etc. local and test).

Is it possible? If yes, how I can do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to `@Configuration` the relevant [@Profile](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html)

> If a @Configuration class is marked with @Profile, all of the @Bean methods and @Import annotations associated with that class will be bypassed unless one or more of the specified profiles are active

Or add `@Profile` for specific `@Bean`s